# Geocoding API - Getting Request_Denied error Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am using Geocoder API to get address from latitude and longitude. For few devices Geocoder is returning empty results. Same latitude and longitude works in Other Devices.

So I am trying to fetch address from latitude and longitude using geocoder API.

Below is my URL:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.89621%2C%2012.89621&key=API_KEY`

I am getting status as `REQUEST_DENIED` Error but I am getting 200 as response status code.

Can anyone pls let me know what is the mistake I am doing and do I need to change anything in the URL. Geocoding API is enabled in console.

Comment: Do you have a valid API_KEY?, you need to one to use this API.

Comment: @Tonnie Yes its valid, I am using the one that is present in console.

Comment: Do you have billing account enabled? Do you apply any restriction on the API key?

Comment: @xomena Yes I have billing account enabled, I have few restriction on APIS, for this account I can use 8 APIS in that geocoding is one of the APIs

Comment: Look at this article in documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied. I guess something is wrong with restriction you apply on your API key.